# how to get individual(s) for given class/individual with given object property using SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have simple ontology called "campus.owl".There is a class called"Lecturer" and which has two sub classes ,RegularLecturer and VisitingLecturer.There is a another class called "Student" which is a sibling class of Lecturer class.
I have created individuals for all the classes.

Student class is joind with Lecture class with "has" object property.

### problem

I want to get some Lecturer/VisitingLecturer individuals for given student individual. Could you please help me to get this result! Thanks in advance!

```
PREFIX rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
PREFIX rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns# 
PREFIX my: http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2010/5/Ontology1275975684120.owl#

SELECT ?lec WHERE { ?lec..........??? }
```

any idea..??

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT ?lec WHERE { ?lec a ?lectype. 
                    ?lectype <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <Lecturer>.
                    <student> <has> ?lec.}
```

Should do it.

Comment: This query does not give the result. consider there are some Lecturer individuals(john,paul) as well as Student individuals(marry,lisa,steven). john and paul is assigned to marry. Actually I want something like this.. "who are the lecturers assigned to marry" Thats only bro..Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: replace <student> above with the URI for mary and you should see something like you want.